# Yii2: The record in DB isn't updating when changing value in html select

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I have an update form and it contains this code
**View**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList([
    '0' => 'Individual',
    '1' => 'Entity',
]) ?>
```

**Action**

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $model = Page::find()->where(['user_id'=>$id])->one();

    if (!Yii::$app->user->can('UpdateOwnPage',['page'=>$model]))
    {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException("You have no access to this page.");
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect('page/'.$model->url);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But the value in my DB table is still 0, it isn't changing at all. What the problem?

Comment: this is only a form field ... show the code for submit and the action for save  please ..

Comment: My fault, I've forgot about it.

Comment: can you show your Page model? the validation rule, also did you save method success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be your validation rules are not respected the just for test try using a $model->save(false)  if the value is saved 
 then check better for validation

```
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) {
      $model->save(false)) ;
      return $this->redirect('page/'.$model->url);


  } else {
      return $this->render('update', [
          'model' => $model,
      ]);
  }
```

you can get  the validatio error this way eg:

```
if ($model->validate()) {
    // all inputs are valid
} else {
  // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
   $errors = $model->errors;
   var_dump($errors);
 }
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.Sorry, I'm new to Yii. How should I validate it?

Comment: answer  update .. otherwise  .. check the single rules in Model

Answer (score 1):

It's not so good security practice but you can add in your model:

```
public function rules()
{
  $rules = [];
  $rules[] = [ $this->attributes(), 'safe' ];
  $rules[] = [ $this->attributes(), 'trim' ];

  return $rules;
}
```